# How can I replace an array that's already assigned?

Tags: c++

my program first asks how many names I want to insert then it stores those names in an array. Now in **case 5** and **void inserisci** I am supposed to develop something that asks you which one of the names you entered you want to change and then what you want to change it to. Thing is, I have no idea how, I've been thinking about this for a while but just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void inserisci(string x[], int q, string name){
    

}

int frequenza (string x[], int d, string nome){
    int conta,i;
    conta=0;
    
    for(i=0; i<d; i++){
        if(x[i]==nome){
        conta=conta+1;
      }
     }
    return conta;
}

void stampa (string x[], int q){
    int i;
        
    cout<<"Elenco: "<<endl;
    for (i=0; i<q; i++){
        cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int ricerca (string x[],int q, string name){
    int pos,i;
    i=0;
    
    while(i<q && x[i]!=name){
        i=i+1;}
    if (i>=q){
        pos= -1;}
    else pos= i;
    
  return pos;
}
 
int minimo (string x[], int q){
    string min;
    int imin;
     
    min=x[0];
    imin=0;
    for (int i=1;i<q;i++){
        if (x[i]<min) {imin=1;
        min=x[i]; }
  }
 return imin;
}

void carica (string x[], int q){
    int i;
    
    for(i=0; i<q; i++){
        cout<<"Inserisci il "<<i+1<<" nome:"<<endl;
        cin>>x[i];
 }
}

void controllo (int &x){
    while (x<=0) {cout<<"Errore! Inserisci un numero positivo:"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
   }
}


int main(){
    int scelta, n, p, f, iminimo;
    string nome;
    bool exit=false;
    cout<<"Quanti nomi vuoi inserire?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    controllo(n);
    string a[n];
    carica(a,n);
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Benvenuto Operatore, cosi desideri fare?"<<endl;
        cout<<"1) Stampa il tuo elenco di nomi"<<endl;
        cout<<"2) Ricerca il minimo"<<endl;
        cout<<"3) Verificare la presenza di un nominativo"<<endl;
        cout<<"4) Calcola la frequenza di un nome"<<endl;
        cout<<"10) Esci"<<endl;
        cin>>scelta;      
        switch (scelta){
            case 1:
                stampa(a,n);
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 2:
                iminimo=minimo(a,n);
                cout<<"Il minimo e: "<<a[iminimo]<<endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Chi cerchi?"<<endl;
                cin>>nome;
                p=ricerca (a,n,nome);
                if (p==-1) cout<<"Non c'e"<<endl;
                else cout<<nome<<" c'e"<<" e si trova in posizione "<<p<<endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"Chi cerchi?"<<endl;
                cin>>nome;
                f=frequenza(a, n, nome);
                cout<<"Il nome "<< nome <<" si ripete  "<< f <<"volte"<<endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 5:
                
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 10:
                exit=true;
                cout<<"Arrivederci Operatore!"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }while (!exit);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `x[q] = name;` -- Or is there some detail that's missing?  That's how you set an array's value at index `q`, so I don't know what you're asking, or if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am trying to change the values that have already been inserted, for example if I were to insert 2 names, let's say Jack and Joe, case 5 would be to select one of these names and then change it to what you want

Comment: So what part of this are you having trouble with?  Your question isn't really focused enough.  My first comment changes the entry at position `q`.  So you find the position of the name in the array and change the name at that position.  Is it searching for the name to change?  If so, you should specify that.  Is it "how do I input values to do this?", then you ask that.

Comment: There is a class in the standard library combining `string x[], int q` into `std::vector<std::string>`. Use that and `std::swap`.

Comment: Vectors are cool and all, but switching to one has no bearing on this question. The answer would be the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is my 20th program so I'm quite new and may not be exactly able to understand or ask the right question. I'm not exactly sure how changing the entry position can help me with my program. I already explained and made an example in my first response, I honestly don't really know how to explain it better. From what I understand the initial values that are stored in the arrays need to be changed with a "mini program" that's supposed to be in case 5 and in void inserisci

Comment: Take a shot at solving this or update the question to show what you've tried. You may only have a tiny mistake, and even if you miss by a mile, you will have provided a baseline around which answers can be constructed. Without that baseline answers really have no place to start, and "First turn on the computer..." makes for a crappy answer.

Comment: Tactical point: When asking a question, prefer to rein in the answers by providing a small program that runs but only does the one thing you are asking about. If the question isn't about user input, preplace all of the user inputs with hard-coded values. Extra code can be hiding extra bugs (or flat out be a bug)  and a tightly focused program makes sure everyone is testing the exact same thing against the exact same conditions. As an added bonus, making this tightly-focused program often result s in you spotting and fixing the bug without asking a question, so if you do it early...

Comment: @sweenish If you take the title question into account "_How can I replace an array that's already assigned?_" I 'm pretty sure that switching to using `vector`s has a bearing on this question.

Comment: If I ignore the parts I choose, I could also provide whatever answer I please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your existing code had an error:

```
string* a = new string[n]; //arrays must have constant sizes, if you need a dynamic array, use the new operator
```

Arrays are allocated from the stack, so they need to have a size determined at compile time. If you need an array with a dynamic size, use the `new` operator, if you really need one.

Here is the code you will need for `case 5:`:

```
case 5:
    cout << "Chi cerchi?" << endl; //which value?
    cin >> nome;
    p = ricerca(a, n, nome); //get the position of the value
    if (p == -1) { cout << "Non c'e" << endl; break; } //if there is no value, exit
    cout << "Nuovo valore?" << endl; //what is the new value?
    cin >> nome;
    inserisci(a, p, nome); //at position p of a, set it to nome
    system("pause");
    break;
```

And here is the code for `inserisci()`:

```
void inserisci(string* x, int q, string newname) { //note the use of pointers for dynamic memory
    x[q] = newname; //position q of x is now newname
}
```

Also, at the end of your code, since we are using dynamic memory, we need to `delete[]` a:

```
delete[] a;
```